# Increment a counter based on number of elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-init

I have a below snippet for showing TABS which is static HTML. But each item would get shown on UI based on some business logic. Based on the number of tabs I need to set a width. For e.g if two tabs are shown then I need to equally divide tabs i.e 50%. when three, it will be 33.3%.

```
 <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
 </ul>
```

Using 'ng-class' I can add runtime classes to apply the width but its increasing the complexity and killing the page as I need to apply the same business logic in ng-class.

Rather, I was trying to use ng-init to get the count to check how many tabs are formed.

```
 <ul ng-init="totalTabs=0">
    <li ng-init="totalTabs=totalTabs+1">1</li>
    <li ng-init="totalTabs=totalTabs+1">2</li>
    <li ng-init="totalTabs=totalTabs+1">3</li>
    <li ng-init="totalTabs=totalTabs+1">4</li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't give me the expected count. Do you have any clue or  suggestions ?

Comment: If you are using ng-repeat, you can get the count based on $index.

Comment: I am not using ng-repeat.. this is a static html.

Comment: If this is static html, then you can add css the normal  way to handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time to use some new features of CSS3. In case you don't know it, there's a new display called **flex**. It allows a lot of things, and one of them is to give elements the same width, based on their parent's width.

You can find a [quick tutorial here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or if you want to be fast :

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    li {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}
```